# How to append to a list inside of a list in python

Tags: python

I'm having trouble adding numbers to a list that is already in a list. For example, say I'm given:

```
L = [[1, 2, 3], [100, 101, 102]]
```

I'm trying to append to `L[1]` to get:

```
L = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [100, 101, 102]]
```

The way I was going about this was `L[1].extend([4, 5, 6])` but was getting the result `None`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, that's `L[0]` you want to append to, not `L[1]`. Indices start at 0.

Second, `L[0].extend([4, 5, 6])` will work fine. It modifies the list and returns `None`. Demo:

```
>>> L = [[1, 2, 3], [100, 101, 102]]
>>> L[0].extend([4, 5, 6])
>>> L
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [100, 101, 102]]
```

Just don't try to do anything with `extend`'s return value, and you should be fine.

Comment: oh whoops, that was a typo, I meant L[0]. And thank you! I didn't know that it changed it, I thought the result meant that it didn't successfully extend it.